# How do I create a series of overlapping selectable images, similar to the ones on this page?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I would like to create a series of overlapping, selectable images similar to the ones at the top of this page: https://www.onedrop.org/en/mission/

Is there a Wordpress plugin I can use to do so, or is it best to code it from scratch using Javascript/CSS?

Comment: You actually don't need javascript. Just a good CSS knowledge. You can do it with `position: absolute` and `z-index`. Wrap the images in a container and play with those properties

Answer (score 0):

Give all the images `position: relative` and control which one is in front (by default) using `z-index`. Set `z-index` to change on `hover` to make the hovered image come to the front.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `CSS` `position`, `:hover` and `z-index`

Here is the fiddle:

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.main img {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
}

.main img:first-child {
  z-index: 4;
  left: -40px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.main img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 3;
  left: 40px;
}

.main img:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: -50px;
}

.main img:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50px;
}

.main img:nth-child(2):hover,
.main img:nth-child(3):hover,
.main img:nth-child(4):hover {
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/04/22/41/atomium-4179270_960_720.jpg" />
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/02/25/17/51/kittens-4020199_960_720.jpg" />
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/18/15/44/france-1049333_960_720.jpg" />
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/17/23/07/abstract-1264071_960_720.png" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** Please adjust image `width` `height` and `positions` as per your requirement :)